# gnuplot.py not cleaning previous graph

Tags: python, gnuplot

Once again a newbie question:
I'm using gnuplot through a python script and I was trying to generate multiple graphs in sequence, varying the content. However I am seeing a strange thing: the second graph looks like it has been drawn on top of the first one, the third on top of the second...well I think you get what I mean. The last graph contains all the lines drawn on the previous graphs.
So I'm sure I must be forgetting to clean something up, but I don't know what. See below a sanitized version of my code, with only the gnuplot related stuff

```
#geting an instance
g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(debug=1, persist=persistScreen)

#formatting
g('set title "' + title + '" font "arial,30"')
g.xlabel(x_label)
g.ylabel(y_label)
g('set auto x')
g('set xdata time')
g('set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"')
g('set format x "%H:%M:%S"')
g('set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"')
g('set xtic rotate by -45 scale 1 font ",16"')
g('set xtics 5')                # xtic per 5 seconds
g('set grid mxtics xtics lt 1 lc rgb ' + GRID_COLOR + ' lt 0 lc rgb ' + GRID_COLOR)
g('set grid ytics')

#plot the file
print "Creating ", outfile, "..."
g('pause 1')
g('set term png size ' + str(self.mPngXSize) + ',' + str(self.mPngYSize) + ' linewidth 3')
g('set out ' + outfile)
g('replot')
g('pause 1')
g('set term x11')
g('pause 1')    

# clean-up
g.reset()
```

So this in short the steps run per graph. Anyone can suggest why it's not working ?

Comment: What about `g('clear')`?

Comment: Adding `code` g('clear') on before or after the reset call causes that a blank (0 bytes long) image is written down. So I suspect that some file operations are still going on by then.